# Proving that $J_n$, the matrix of all $1$'s, is positive semidefinite, and that $x^*J_nx = \left\vert\sum x_i \right\vert^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

This one seems really easy to me, but my professor posted a video where he solved using what, to my eye, seems like a really roundabout approach.

Here's my approach.

To start, $J_nx$ is a vector whose entries are all $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i.$

Then $x^*J_nx = \overline{x_1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + ... + \overline{x_n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\overline{x_i}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = \overline{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = \left\vert\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right\vert^2$.

Which basically proves everything, since the modulus of a complex number is positive (or zero), and $x$ was chosen arbitrarily.

Right?

Comment: Seems right to me. What was your professor's roundabout approach? Maybe he uses tools that are more useful in a general setting (or maybe it was just roundabout ^^).

Comment: Oh jeez. Nevermind. I'm an idiot. He did it exactly the way I did; the proof was just so short that I didn't realize that he started a new problem.

Well, thanks for your thoughts all the same. lol

Comment: In any case, it's good to see that you can find the same result by yourself :)